# File path to file name String converter not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, converters

Using a wpf `ListBox` I'm trying to display a list of filename without displaying the full path (more convenient for user).

Data comes from an `ObservableCollection` which is filled using Dialog.

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _VidFileDisplay = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] {""});

    public ObservableCollection<string> VidFileDisplay
    {
        get { return _VidFileDisplay; }
        set { _VidFileDisplay = value; }
    }
```

In the end I want to select some items and get back the full file path. For this I have a converter :

```
  public class PathToFilenameConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
          //return Path.GetFileName(value.ToString());
          string result = null;
          if (value != null)
          {
              var path = value.ToString();

              if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) == false)
                  result = Path.GetFileName(path);
          }
          return result;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
          return value;
      }
  }
```

Which I bind to my listbox itemsource :

```
<ListBox x:Name="VideoFileList" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Template="{DynamicResource BaseListBoxControlStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource BaseListBoxItemStyle}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.VidFileDisplay, Converter={StaticResource PathToFileName},ElementName=Ch_Parameters, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVidNames,ElementName=Ch_Parameters, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Without the converter, it is working fine (but of course this is the full path displayed in the listbox). With the converter I have one character per line... displaying this :

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.String]
```

Where am I wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **`ItemsSource` binding converter applies to the whole list** and not to each item in the collection. If you want to apply your converter per item you need to do it `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListBox x:Name="VideoFileList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.VidFileDisplay, ElementName=Ch_Parameters}" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource PathToFileName}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you